# integrate dotCover with TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, dotcover

Is there a tutorial somehwere or can somebody explain how to integrate dotCover with TFS? I want to run dotCover (probably the console runner?) as part of the team build process and would like to generate a report that is integrated in the TFS build report.

Answer (score 2):

Running dotCover itself will be easy enough.  Simply add an InvokeProcess activity to the build workflow and call the appropriate command line options.  I've got a [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/08/how-to-build-vb6-apps-with-tfs-team.html) showing how this is done (calling the VB6 compiler in my example) but it should show you what you need to do.

The hard part will be integrating a report into the TFS build report.  All you'll really be able to do is slightly customise the log - see Ewald Hoffmans [blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/02/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-13-Get-control-over-the-Build-Output.aspx) (and series) on customising the build if you want to do this.